# Obtener el ID relacionado con un maximo con SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

Tengo el siguiente problema: tengo una serie de registros que contienen fecha, código de tienda y id.
Quiero obtener el id del registro con la mayor fecha (es decir, el más reciente) para cada tienda (es decir para cada código de tienda diferente).

Si hago:

```
select ID, CODIGO_TIENDA FROM tabla
where FECHA IS NOT NULL
group by CODIGO_TIENDA, ID
order by FECHA desc;
```

Obtengo todos los registros (cosa que no quiero), debido a que el group by lleva el campo ID e obviamente la pareja ID, CODIGO_TIENDA no se repite y entonces es como si no hiciera nada.

COSAS QUE HE INTENTADO:
Preguntándole a CHAT_GPT me dice que haga un `inner join` con la tabla y así obtenga las fechas (y así el `group by` funcionaria), pero esta opción tampoco sirve porque podría darse la mala suerte de que dos registros diferentes tuvieran la misma fecha.
He visto también que alguna gente usa el `PARITTION OVER`, pero según dan a entender en las diferentes páginas donde lo he visto este lo hace sobre toda la tabla y quisiera evitar tener que hacerlo ya que esta tabla tendrá muchas filas ( > 10^5) [obviamente el select no lo hace sobre toda la tabla ya que las columnas mencionadas tienen índices].
Con el partition over se haría así:

```
select A.*
from (select A.*, row_number() over (partition by A.codigo_tienda order by A.FECHA desc) as rn
FROM TablaA A
where A.FEHCA IS NOT NULL) A
where A.rn = 1;
```

**Que me gustaría obtener**: Una query que haga lo especificado, pero con un rendimiento aceptable

Observación: No se si será realmente importante pero observad que FECHA puede ser nulo.

Comment: ¿En caso de dos fechas iguales para una tienda, qué ID quieres?

Comment: @PabloLozano el más alto, aunque me da igual

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Se me ocurre lo siguiente: Obtener tienda y fecha y luego buscar la mayor ID que coincida:

```sql
select max(id), codigo_tienda, fecha
from tabla
where (codigo_tienda, fecha) in (
  select codigo_tienda, MAX(fecha) as f
  from tabla
  where fecha is not null
  group by codigo_tienda
)
group by codigo_tienda, fecha;
```

Lo he probado con este *fiddle*: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/4CM8teHrCPDnuMV7nXGsEG/0

Answer (score 1):

Similar o con la misma idea de la `SELECT` anterior de @pablo-lozano, pero creo que es mejor evitar por temas de rendimiento el `SELECT..IN`.

La misma consulta puedes generarla utilizando `INNER JOIN`.

Sobre el mismo escenario anterior puedes usar la siguiente SQL, y obtendrás el mismo resultado.

```
select max(T2.id), T2.Codigo_tienda,T2.fecha from tabla T2
INNER JOIN 
  (
  select codigo_tienda, MAX(fecha) as fecha
  from tabla
  where fecha is not null
  group by codigo_tienda
  ) T1 ON (T1.fecha=T2.fecha) and (T1.codigo_tienda=T2.codigo_tienda) 
group by codigo_tienda,fecha
```

Es casi seguro que si tienes muchos registros debería ser más rápida.

Comment: en efecto he hecho algunas pruebas y parece ser que tu query ofrece algo más de rendimiento (~ 10% [aunque en algunos casos extremos la mejora es aún más grande]), aún así seguiré aceptando la de pablo dado que fue la primera que entro que ya me solucionaba lo que pedia, pero muchas gracias por presentar una solución más eficiente!